# array declaration of shellscript doesnot work in scheduled cron job?

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I have created a shell script named "script.sh" which reads an arrays elements and prints it on terminal. The script is as follows:

```
 arr=("hello" "world")
for i in ${arr[@]}
do
echo  $i;
done
```

It gives expected output i.e 'Hello World' on executing it in terminal, but if I schedule the same script in crontab jobs to get executed automatically every minute and store the output in another file,the job fails and gives

`/home/vikash/script.sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected` error.

The crontab job to execute the script every minute and store the output in another file   is as follows:

```
* * * * * $HOME/script.sh >> $HOME/output.log 2>&1
```

How to use array in this scenario?? please help.

Comment: Do you have `#!/bin/bash` at the top of `script.sh`?

Comment: ... or, alternatively, a `SHELL=/bin/bash` line in your crontab, assuming your version of `cron` supports that, which most modern Linux distros seem to...

Comment: Oh! yes I did not add #!/bin/bash. Thanks its working now.

Answer (score 6):

Add this before the first line of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: in my case the shebang was not on the firstline (I had a # line before the shebang). So yes it must be absolutely the first line of the script.

Answer (score 0):

if this question is still valid, just run your script with

```
bash script.sh
```

I also tried it with sh somehow it is not working with sh but with bash it suns smooth.