# Error 'Syntax error: "(" unexpected' when declaring arrays in bash

Tags: bash, cron

Same problem as [this OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209607/array-declaration-of-shellscript-doesnot-work-in-scheduled-cron-job), but must be a seperate cause.

The following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
arr=("cat" "dog" "bird")
```

Works interactively (debian) but fails when called by crontab with:

```
/bin/sh: 2: /path/zero_check.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I've tried with `#!/bin/bash` shebang, and declaring array with `declare -a arr=("cat" "dog" "bird")`, to no effect.

Any idea why?

Comment: How are you calling your script in crontab?

Comment: The error message is a clear indicator that Bash is actually not used to execute the script.

Comment: I tried with both shebangs, but just copied the script at a different point to the error.  The solution below works.

Comment: `bash` or `sh` best for cron?

Comment: @geotheory it really depends on what you want to do. If you need arrays, then Bash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify your interpreter explicitly in the crontab entry. Use

```
bash /path/zero_check.sh
```

rather than

```
/path/zero_check.sh
```

Comment: this shouldn't be the issue if the script already contains the `#!/bin/bash` header.

Comment: I think I just copied the working script at the wrong point.  The solution works.

Comment: If this is the answer, then there's another problem in your script you are ignoring.  :(

Comment: @SaintHax Agreed; the problem is the incorrect shebang line (uses `/bin/sh` instead of '/bin/bash`); overriding that by running it with `bash` really just hides the problem, it'd be better to fix the shebang (see fedorqui's answer).

Answer (score 8):

The problem here is that you are using this shebang:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Whereas [arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) are something Bash specific that shell does not allow.

So to make it work, change the shebang of your script to Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the documentation,
i had an old script to run which had an Syntax Error in the Shebang:

`#/bin/bash`

instead of

`#!/bin/bash`

Also check the Script is executable of course.

Comment: YES! I have been going insane the past two days because I forgot the exclamation point. This saves what little sanity I have remaining.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar problem with incorrect bash function declarations. This works OK from the command line, but it causes cron to fail...

```
function test () { ... }
```

Cron should save the errors in /var/mail

I also recommend linting with "shellcheck" because it found another error I didn't notice.