# Bash script GitLab shared runner

Tags: bash, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am attempting to use a shared runner to run a script which handles env vars necessary for deployment. The section of my YAML config that is failing is:

```
release:
  stage: release
  image: docker:latest
  only:
    - master
  services:
    - docker:dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay
  before_script:
    - docker version
    - docker info
    - docker login -u ${CI_REGISTRY_USER} -p ${CI_BUILD_TOKEN} ${CI_REGISTRY}
  script:
    - dckstart=$(cat dockerfile-start)
    - export > custom_vars
    - chmod +x scripts/format-variables.sh
    - bash scripts/format-variables.sh
    - dckenv=$(cat custom_vars)
    - dckfin=$(cat dockerfile-finish)
    - echo -e "$dckstart\n$dckenv\n$dckfin" >> Dockerfile
    - rm dockerfile-start dockerfile-finish custom_vars
    - docker build -t ${CI_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}:latest --pull .
    - docker push ${CI_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}:latest
  after_script:
    - docker logout ${CI_REGISTRY}
```

This step fails & gives the error:

> $ chmod +x scripts/format-variables.sh
>   $ bash scripts/format-variables.sh
>   /bin/sh: eval: line 101: bash: not found

I have attempted:

- `/bin/bash scripts/format-variables.sh`

  > /bin/sh: eval: line 114: /bin/bash: not found
- `cd scripts && ./format-variables.sh`

  > /bin/sh: eval: line 116: ./format-variables.sh: not found
- `--shell /bin/bash scripts/format-variables.sh`

  > /bin/sh: eval: line 114: --shell: not found

The final attempt was an idea I grabbed from [the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/#shbash-shells). I have not specified the shared runners to use but I assume the one being used is UNIX based as all other UNIX commands work.

Is it possible to do this via a shared runner or do I need to get a dedicated runner for this?

**NOTE**: *I have to use Bash for this script & not Shell due to using arrays. If I were to use Shell, I would come up with the error mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37004196/error-syntax-error-unexpected-when-declaring-arrays-in-bash)*

Comment: there's no bash in that image, you need to install it. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40944479/how-to-use-bash-with-an-alpine-based-docker-image/40944512

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @IronBishop, I went with this fix in the end. Put an answer & I will accept

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `docker:latest` image doesn't contain `bash`, to save space. You can either install it (see [How to use bash with an Alpine based docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40944479/how-to-use-bash-with-an-alpine-based-docker-image/40944512)) or use a different base image (like CentOS or Ubuntu).

Answer (score 2):

Use an image that has bash installed like `CentOS` or `Ubuntu`.